# If I use vim modified a file without backup, can I restore the contents?

Tags: osx, vim

I use vim changed a file on my Mac:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:testdj ldl$ vim urls.py
```

and I did not backup the file, can I restore the `urls.py`'s contents?

Comment: If you still have the file open, you can undo changes with `:u`. If you closed the file, tough luck.

Comment: @Munir Oh, tough luck.

Comment: Did you manually write and close the file? Or did something crash? In the case of the latter, you might have a backup `*.swp` file around that you can recover from.

Comment: @Sparhawk I write and close the file manually.

Comment:  Yep, no other way that I can think of, except for perhaps Linux-ninja ways of extracting from RAM. Hopefully you have regular backups of your file system!

Comment: Time to learn how to use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file is gone. Restore from backup (this should be fairly easy if you have [macOS' Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(macOS)) running).

For the future, you may want to configure Vim to automatically backup files that you edit.  This may be done by editing your `.vimrc` configuration file and including the line

```
set backup
```

You may read about other options influencing how and where backups are created by reading [the help about the `backup` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backup').

If you, for example, want to collect all backup files in one single place, you may set [the `backupdir` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupdir') to some directory.